# How to align height of all tabs in horizontal ul menu in css

Tags: css, list, menu, unordered

Hello I have ul menu with fixed width and auto height but some links are too long  and they occupy 2 lines. How to align high of all tabs accordingly to the highest one?

Comment: @Ace Zul without your code share anybody can;t helping you so please share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: ..or in an editor of your choice

Comment: provide your code please

Answer (score 0):

This is it, buddy: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/UFUZETI/1/edit)

Screenshot:

[image]

CSS:

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:lightGrey;
  padding:5px;
  width:100px;
  display:table-cell;
}
ul{
  padding:0px;
  display:table-row;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      Link 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Longest Largest Biggest and the Baddest Link
    </li>
    <li>
      Link 3
    </li>
  </ul>
```